# GCC fatal error: quit.h no such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, c-standard-library

I am learning C for an operating systems course and have just finished writing this program as per the textbook instructions:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "quit.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *direntry;

        arg_check(2, argc, "Specify a directory\n", 1);

        if ( (dir = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
                quit("opendir", 1);

        while ((direntry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
           printf("%10d %s\n", direntry->d_ino, direntry->d_name);

        closedir(dir);
        exit(0);
}
```

This code is exactly copied from the textbook, but quit.h appears to be causing the compile to file. I have tried switching "quit.h" to ,  and "quit", but none of these have worked, and I cannot find other questions about this specific issue.

Comment: Is the file `quit.h` located in the same directory as your C source file?

Comment: or to rephrase the question - where is the file quit.h

Comment: Which text book?

Comment: "This code is exactly copied from the textbook" - was the content and relative location of `quit.h` given a similar affordance?

Comment: If quit.h file resides in different directory from your source directory, you can compile it using -I compile option.

Answer (score 0):

> ## include "quit.h"

The word `#include` (with its hash `#` prefix) means that a file has to be read in; the content of that file (quit.h in this case) is processed exactly as if it was typed inside the program. Suppose you have a file name "test.h" which contains the single line

```
// this is a test
```

if you a have a program like this:

```
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
...
```

the compiler processes (*sees*) exactly these lines:

```
// this is a test
int main(int argc, char **argv)
...
```

The file name specified after `#include` can be enclosed with angles or quotes. Conventionally, if angles are used, like

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

this means that the file (*stdio.h* in this case) is some *system* or *standard* file or so - in other simple words, someone else has written that file for you. If quotes are used, instead, the file specified is considered somehow part of the program you are compiling. **Your quit.h** seems like this. So you must have a file named `quit.h`. If you change that "quit.h" to "quit", a file named `quit` must be present in the same directory of the file you are compiling. (*Actually things are more complicated, but don't mind it for now*). Read your book, somewhere it should explain what is that file "quit.h".